# Programatically fire Treview item selction event in wpf

Tags: wpf, view, tree

I'm working on WPF project where I populate a tree view (MainWindow.xaml)using a Class called SampleTreeItem (SampleTreeView class). This tree view shows files from the selected folder. when user clicks the tree item (mainWindow.cs), the code in the background opens the file, serializes it and extract the data from it.

Now I'm adding a checkbox to this tree through the class using header template.
There is event called OnItemSelected (in Mainwindow.cs) which gets fired when I select item from tree view.

I'm trying to handle the click event of the checkbox in Sampletree.cs and I want to fire OnItemSelected from mainwindow.cs  when user clicks on the check box.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 private void filesTreeView_OnItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SampleFileTreeItem treeViewItem = e.Source as SampleFileTreeItem;
            if (treeViewItem == null)
                return;

            OpenSampleFile(treeViewItem.FilePath);

        }
```

This is the click event in the SampleTree.cs file.

```
public void CompareSamples_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //RoutedEvent routedEvent = e.RoutedEvent;
            //e.Handled= true; 
            //e.Source = this;
            //RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(routedEvent, e);

            RoutedEvent routedEvent = TreeView.SelectedItemChangedEvent;
            e.Source = this;
            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(routedEvent, e);

            if (compareSamplesCheckbox.IsChecked == true)
            {
               OnSelected(args);
            }
            else
            {
                //object sender, RoutedEventArgs e

            }


    }
```

I don't know what I'm missing here but I cant fire  OnItemSelected (mainWinodw) from SampleTree.cs.

Let me know if anyone has any thoughts on it. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that `OnSelected(..)` is an event handler. So in your code you need not to call an event handler, but to raise an event for the `UIElement`:

```
public void CompareSamples_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEvent routedEvent = TreeView.SelectedItemChangedEvent;
    e.Source = this;
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args = new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object>(oldVal, newVal, routedEvent);

    if (compareSamplesCheckbox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        yourTreeView.RaiseEvent(args);
    }
    else
    {
        //object sender, RoutedEventArgs e
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have just started working with events. Can you please tell me how to get the old and new values in the RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs.

Comment: It depends on logic, which you have in your application. E.g. yourTreeView.Items[X], yourTreeView.Items[Y]

Comment: Also, I have fired this event on  Checkbox . Since I don't have instance of               compareSamplesCheckbox.RaiseEvent(args) ,

Comment: If event for TreeView, then you have to fire it on instance of TreeVew and so on.

Comment: Yes you are right. But mytreevire control is in defined in Mainwindow.xaml and class SampleFiletreeItem is the source of the Tree View.

Comment: I have answered your question - How to programmatically fire a TreeView's ItemSelection event. I hope the solution I have posted works for you. If you have another questions, then think about what you want to ask and post new question. Please read also [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)